# CSS Editor with ability to preview in IE6, IE7, Safari 3?

Tags: css, browser, editor, rendering, preview

I realize the question of a good CSS editor has been asked dozens of times here on SO. However, I am specifically searching for one with preview functionality for a variety of browser rendering engines.

My requirements:

- *Must* be able to render IE6, IE7, and Safari 3.0.
- Other current rendering engines a major plus.
- Price is not a factor.

I have been looking at [Aptana](http://aptana.com/), [Stylizer](http://www.skybound.ca/), and [TopStyle](http://www.topstyle4.com/), but I'd rather not download a number of trial installers, only to find that none of them are what I'm looking for.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the new [Expression Web](http://www.microsoft.com/Expression/products/Web_Overview.aspx) from Microsoft, you get the [SuperPreview](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/dd565874.aspx), which will render in multible browsers, including IE6-8 and FF

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at [Expression Web 3](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Web_Overview.aspx), especially at SuperPreview:

> **SuperPreview**
>
> Expression Web provides new tools to make sure that the pages in your site work in multiple browsers.
>
> Using SuperPreview, you can preview and compare pages simultaneously in multiple browsers, even in multiple versions of Internet Explorer. You can also compare browser views against a comprehensive mock-up ("comp") image.
>
> You can select individual elements within a page and see details about each selected element, helping you quickly find and fix cross-browser layout and positioning errors.

Basically it's a side-by-side or overlapping view on steroids which is also able to track each element from your page and where it goes in different browsers.